# Custom AlertDialog size being ignored

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have a custom `alertdialog` thats 250dp by 300dp, but when its rendered, the dimensions basically become `match_parent`. From my understanding, this may be caused by passing `null` to `LayoutInflater.inflate()`, but I am producing this custom dialog from a `fragment`(in `onPostExecute()` of an `asynctask` specifically), not an `adapter`, so I'm not really sure how to obtain a reference to the parent `viewgroup`.

**layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ad_dialog_background">

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="dismiss"
    android:id="@+id/dismissButton_ad"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="#484848" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dialogTitle_ad"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Quote Request Successful" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="148dp"
    android:text="Company XYZ:\n\nhas a special on X items from thus and thus a date to thus and thus a date"
    android:id="@+id/text_ad"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialogTitle_ad"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionButtonOne_ad"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/actionButtonOne_ad"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/actionButtonOne_ad"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_list"
    android:textColor="#f7f7f7"
    android:layout_above="@+id/actionButtonTwo_ad"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/actionButtonTwo_ad"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/actionButtonTwo_ad"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:textSize="11dp"
    android:text="dssd" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/actionButtonTwo_ad"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_list"
    android:textColor="#f7f7f7"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/actionButtonThree_ad"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_list"
    android:textColor="#f7f7f7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actionButtonTwo_ad"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:textSize="11dp" />
```

**fragment.java:**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_dialog, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setView(view);
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
//findViewsById()...
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Where are you testing it on? i.e on which device on emulator?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri , on a device

Comment: The reason I asked which device is because if it's mdpi or ldpi then the resolution will be low and based on do sizes you've given the layout it might take the whole width. What's the model?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri samsung s4, so what do you suggest? changing measurement unit? increase size?

Comment: If you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16511081/1306419, the width of the device screen is `391dp` and the width you are specifying is `300dp`. Is your dialog completely full screen? Try decreasing the width and see what happens.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri, i just tried adjusting the width to a smaller size, and also setting it to match_parent, but the height is still being exxagerated

Comment: @ShobhitPuri, i found my error sir, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was using an `AlertDialog` instead of a `Dialog` and calling `setContentView(R.layout.myview)` on the `Dialog` object.